# How to pass variable from @controller to @controlleradvice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

right now I make custom handler using controlleradvice and is working well. I want to add additional info to the custom validation that "the invoice process has been failed". how do I achieve that ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define you own exception object and uses it to pass the data from the controller method to the exception handler method.

First define an exception as :

```java
public class InvoiceException extends RuntimeException {
   
    private Long invoiceId;
    private String additionalInfo;
}
```

Then in the controller if you check that if violates the related business rules, create an instance of this exception and throw it :

```java
public class InvoiceController {

  
    @PostMapping("/invoice")
    public Long processInvoice(InvoiceRequest request){
       
          if(fail) {
             throw new InvoiceException(invoiceId, "foobar");
          }       ​
   ​}

}
```

In the `@ContorllerAdvice` , you can then access these data from the exception instance :

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {

 ​@ExceptionHandler(InvoiceException.class)
 ​public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handle(InvoiceException ex) {
 ​
      
 ​}
}
```

Comment: how about if we have a lot of API return ? can we make global so that we can just pass it

Comment: make what global？

Comment: the invoice exception. if there are many end point in controlle, can we make global class so that we dont need to create one by one class

Comment: why don't try it by yourself ?

Comment: thanks mr, i can finally solve it with your example.